# Is `which` lying to me?

Tags: ubuntu, git, path

I installed git via `apt-get`, but found that the version was hopelessly outdated, so I then [installed git from source](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/). The end result is rather puzzling:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.0.4
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.6
```

It appears that `which` is lying to me...which seems unlikely. What is actually going on here, and how can I get a bare call to git to run the correct version?

Comment: what shows `whereis git`? and less probable, what shows `type git`?

Comment: Why not simply uninstall the version you got from apt-get if you don't want it?

Comment: Did you remove the binary version from `apt-get`?

Comment: @hmontoliu useful commands! I didn't know about either of those. `whereis git`: `git: /usr/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz`. `type git`: `git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)`. What does "git is hashed" mean?

Comment: @ Zoredache, quanta: Yep, that seems like a sensible thing to do. I just like to understand what's going on, in addition to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`which` is telling the truth.  Your shell is lying to you.

```
git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)
```

means that your shell has cached this location of "git" and is using the cached path rather than searching $PATH again.  Use `hash -r` to clear the cache and make the shell search $PATH for the new git at `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: That was it! Thanks, for both the solution and the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up an alias for git in your shell?

```
$ alias git="/bin/echo This is not the git you are looking for"
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ git --version
This is not the git you are looking for --version
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.4.1
$ type git
git is aliased to `/bin/echo This is not the git you are looking for'
$ unalias git
$ type git
git is /usr/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 1.7.4.1
```